# NameError: name 'model' is not defined

Tags: model, google-colaboratory, nameerror, stable-diffusion

I'm trying to render a video input in Stable Diffusion (on the Google Colab v0.5), but when I try to run the program, it says `NameError: name 'model' is not defined`.

I've tried looking for solutions on this website but I don't understand them; I'm new to all this. Could anyone tell me in layman's terms what the issue is here and how to fix it?